# How to get the access token using verification code via jso oAuth 2.0 lib for Basecamp?

Tags: jquery, oauth-2.0, basecamp

what is working:

According to this [documentation](https://github.com/basecamp/api/blob/master/sections/authentication.md#oauth-2-from-scratch)

I'm able to able to successfully fetch the verification code from the Basecamp authentication server.
e.g `http://127.0.0.1:8020/abc/index.html?code=xxxxxxx&state=yyyyyy-yyyyyyy-yyy-yyyy-yyyyyyy`

I'm using [jso oAuth 2.0](https://github.com/andreassolberg/jso), and not able to understand that how can i get the access token in exchange of verification code ?

if anyone has worked with this library and know how to achieve what i want to, then pls share your experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**jso** seems to only implement the `implicit` Oauth2 flow. You are getting a code because  Basecamp implements a different flow (the authorization_code grant).

Once you get the code, you are supposed to call another endpoint to get the access_token (see step 4 in the docs you mention).

Comment: Thx for sharing this imp piece of info. Do you have any oAuth 2.0 library in your mind which could work with this New Basecamp api (having authorization_code grant)?

Comment: That depends on the backend you are using, because for the auth_code to work, you typically need a server side component. There are many out there (e.g. passport for node, oauth2 for php).